# How can I multiply spaces in a string by the for-loop iterator?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to run a for-loop that adds a space each time it iterates, so that the text forms a diagonal line, but I can't find the integer value of the iterator

I've tried the following:

```
for x in string:
    print(" "*x+x)
```

but that throws an error because x is a string, not a number. I've also tried:

```
for x in string:
    print(" "*string.find(x)+x)
```

but when characters are duplicated in the string, you of course get the number of spaces to the first instance of that character.

Is it possible to access the actual integer value of the iterator so I can multiply spaces by it?

Code solutions I've tried

```
for x in string:
    print(" "*x+x)
```

and

```
for x in string:
    print(" "*string.find(x)+x)
```

first code yields TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

second code yields

```
o
 l
  d

    m
     a
      c
  d
o
         n
     a
 l
  d

              h
     a
  d

     a

                    f
     a
                      r
    m
```

Comment: Use `enumerate`, like `for c,x in enumerate(string)`. `c` is the index of the letter `x` within `string`.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Python iterator that returns both the index and contents of a sequence: `enumerate`:

```
text = "Old MacDonald had a farm"
for pad, char in enumerate(text):
    print(' '*pad + char)
```

`pad` takes on the values 0 through len(text)-1.

Output:

```
O
 l
  d

    M
     a
      c
       D
        o
         n
          a
           l
            d

              h
               a
                d

                  a

                    f
                     a
                      r
                       m
```

If you prefer a solution a little closer to what you've already learned, simply iterate over the length of the string, and then index that character for your output.

```
text = "Old MacDonald had a farm"
for pad in range(len(text)):
    print(' '*pad + text[pad] )
```

Comment: Could also use `str.rjust` here too

Comment: @Jaba Good idea: another "baby step" past what OP already knows.

Comment: `for pad, char in enumerate(text, 1): print(char.rjust(pad))` Was gonna post as an answer but didn't want to steal your thunder. Didn't want to confuse OP just looking to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate` to get the loop index along with `x`:

```py
for i, x in enumerate(string):
    print(" "*i+x)
```

As you noted, the second method fails because `find` returns the first occurrence. You could get around that by using the `start` and `end` arguments, but figuring out what to use for them is probably more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple illustration of multiplication with space:

```
 `x = '*'
for u in range(0,2000):
    for k in range(0,11):
        for i in range(0,6):
            print(i*x,'    '*k,i*x)
        for j in range(6,0,-1):
            print(j*x,'    '*k,j*x)
    for k in range(10,0,-1):
        for i in range(0,6):
            print(i*x,'    '*k,i*x)
        for j in range(6,0,-1):
            print(j*x,'    '*k,j*x)`
```

For entertainment run this code in V.S CODE and enjoy animation.....HeHeHeHeHeHeHeHeHeHeHe........